# Is there a C++ equivalent to Geopandas.sjoin, since it is running very slow on Python?

Tags: python, c++, shapefile, geopandas

I have a set of polygons (around 6000 polygons) all which have been classified into classes (say A to D). And I have a set of points (around 10M). I am using Geopandas sjoin function to check in which polygon the points fall and to then classify each point as well. Unfortunately, this process is really slow in Python. I was wondering if it is possible to do the same in C++?

Let me clarify:
I have a shapefile that contains data as follows:

| id_polygon | class | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | polygon(...) |
| 2 | B | polygon(...) |
| 3 | C | polygon(...) |

Now, I also have some geometry points as below:

| id_point | geometry |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | point(...) |
| 2 | point(...) |
| 3 | point(...) |

Now, I am using geopandas.sjoin, so that I can identify where each point falls in the polygon and assign it a class accordingly.

```py
polygon_sf = gpd.read_file("polygons.shp")
points_sf = gpd.read_file("points.shp")

join_data = gpd.sjoin(points_sf, polygon_sf, how='left', op="within")
```

So, the above sjoin function does manage to get what I want, and in the end I get the following table (where each point has the assigned class):

| id_point | class | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | point(...) |
| 2 | A | point(...) |
| 3 | C | point(...) |

The issue I have right now is that the code is just too slow (I have many points to check, and it is taking quite long). I was wondering if there is any way to do the same operation in C++. I did some Google and Stackoverflow search and I couldn't find anything to help me. I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: Can you install `pygeos`, and check again? If that package is installed, GeoPandas will make use of it, and it will typically speed up operations like the spatial join (the actual spatial query part of the join is then performed in the C++ GEOS library).

Comment: I didn't know about that. I will try it. Thanks a lot.